# Parallel execution of MERGE commands on JDBC driver is not working

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am running ~22 MERGE commands in parallel on the same JDBC connection. I am committing the transaction after all the parallel executions complete. I have turned on explicit transactions. Below is the MERGE commands I am using:

```
MERGE INTO _1 AS A USING ( select $1:Id::VARCHAR as Id,  $1:modifiedUtc::NUMBER as MODIFIEDUTC,  $1:VersionId::NUMBER as VersionId,  $1 as DATA FROM '@EXTERNAL_AWS_STAGE/group1/' (FILE_FORMAT => JSON_FORMAT) ) AS B  ON A.Id = B.Id  WHEN MATCHED AND A.VersionId < B.VersionId  THEN UPDATE SET A.VersionId = B.VersionId, A.MODIFIEDUTC = B.MODIFIEDUTC, A.DATA = B.DATA  WHEN NOT MATCHED  THEN INSERT (Id, MODIFIEDUTC, VersionId, DATA) VALUES (B.Id, B.MODIFIEDUTC, B.VersionId, B.DATA);
```

`MERGE INTO _2 AS A USING ( select $1:Id::VARCHAR as Id,  $1:modifiedUtc::NUMBER as MODIFIEDUTC,  $1:VersionId::NUMBER as VersionId,  $1 as DATA FROM '@EXTERNAL_AWS_STAGE/group2/' (FILE_FORMAT => JSON_FORMAT) ) AS B  ON A.Id = B.Id  WHEN MATCHED AND A.VersionId < B.VersionId  THEN UPDATE SET A.VersionId = B.VersionId, A.MODIFIEDUTC = B.MODIFIEDUTC, A.DATA = B.DATA  WHEN NOT MATCHED  THEN INSERT (Id, MODIFIEDUTC, VersionId, DATA) VALUES (B.Id, B.MODIFIEDUTC, B.VersionId, B.DATA);`

With three identical tables, The problem is that some tables are not getting updated while the others are. It's not that a particular table is not getting updated. Sometimes, say table _1 is getting updated and sometimes not. I verified that executeUpdate(query) method returns 1 for all the MERGE commands, indicating that one row is either updated or inserted for ALL the tables, but the select * from _1 returns 0 rows for some of them. The codebase either commits or rolls back the transaction and in the end closes the connection.

When I try to run the same MERGE commands via Snowflake Worksheets, I could see that data is updated in all tables.

Any pointers would be greatly helpful.

Some important observations:

1. Since we must have updates processed within a transaction boundary, we are calling Connection.setAutoCommit(false). If this is not enabled, above issues are not observed.
2. We are sending queries in batches of 20 to Snowflake for execution. All the 20 queries are fired concurrently using the same database connection. Every batch of 20 MERGE commands is followed by a pause of 2 seconds.
3. If we try to execute MERGE commands sequentially, the issues are not observed. Even after a couple of active locks on tables, the commits are successful and data is updated in the tables.
4. For the data tables which are empty, even Snowflake History says that the MERGE commands completed successfully and the row count for every MERGE command was 1.
5. SHOW TRANSACTIONS command shows an active transaction only till the time the transaction is active. After successful commit, no active transaction is shown by this command.
6. SHOW LOCKS command shows variable number of locks, ranging from 1 to more than the number of tables involved.
7. If we check the history of the query id returned in the result-set of SHOW LOCKS command, we find that the query has completed successfully.

Please provide any pointers which might help in further identifying the issue.

Comment: Are you seeing all of the queries in query_history on Snowflake?  Trying to determine whether this more related to the scripting that you are using, rather than a Snowflake issue.  Also, are there any locks remaining when the process is finished?  That would indicate that some of the statements were not committed.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the latest Snowflake JDBC connector and explicitly setting the multi-statement options as per the following?
https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/jdbc-using.html#multi-statement-jdbc